# web2py SQLFORM.factory not working when function called with vars

Tags: python, web2py

I have a menu item that calls the function `get_report_date()`, along with a variable `next_url`.

```
(T('Return Register'), False, '#', [(T('Daily List'), False, URL('default', 'get_report_date', vars=dict(next_url='returns_daily_list')), []),
(T('Full Register'), False, URL('default', 'returns_register'), []),
```

I want the function `get_report_date` to get user input for `report_date` through a form made with `SQLFORM.factory`, and pass it on as a `var` to the `next_url`.

```
def get_report_date():
    report_date = request.now
    session.flash = 'I am here'
    next_url = request.vars.next_url
    form = SQLFORM.factory(Field('report_date', 'date', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()))

    if form.process().accepted:
        report_date = form.vars.report_date
            redirect(URL('%s' % next_url, vars=dict(report_date=report_date)))
    else:
        session.flash = T('Incorrect Date: %s' % form.vars.report_date)
        redirect(URL('index_n'))
```

I do have the corresponding `default/get_report_date.html` with the minimal code as below:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=form}}
```

But the form is never opened, and the function directly goes to the `else` option and flashes `Incorrect Date:None`.

I cannot understand where I am erring. Can someone point out my mistake and advise how to get the functionality? I will need the `get_report_date()` functionality for many reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two conditions under which `form.process().accepted` will be `False`: (1) when the empty form is first sent to the browser (i.e., it has not been submitted), (2) when the form has been submitted but fails validation. Your code assumes only the second case and fails to provide a path for the first case. It should instead look something like:

```
    if form.process().accepted:
        report_date = form.vars.report_date
        redirect(URL('%s' % next_url, vars=dict(report_date=report_date)))
    elif form.errors:
        session.flash = T('Incorrect Date: %s' % form.vars.report_date)
        redirect(URL('index_n'))

    return dict(form=form)
```

Note, as an alternative to your conditional logic, you can make use of the `next` and `onfailure` arguments (as documented [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#The-process-and-validate-methods)) to control what happens upon form submission.